# How to properly copy and return a CGFloat

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code where I copy my float that I need to remember.

```
- (void) rememberThisFloatForLater:(CGFloat)floatToRemember {

self.rememberedFloat = &(floatToRemember);

}
```

And here is self.rememberedFloat in the header file...

```
@property (assign) CGFloat *rememberedFloat;
```

My issue is here when I try to return the remembered float. When I return it, I get 6.92867051318e-310 and I should get 3.14159265359 because that is what floatToRemember equals. Where am I going wrong?

```
- (CGFloat) floatYouShouldRemember {

return *(self.rememberedFloat);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGFloat is a primitive type. It would be very, very, *very* unusual that you would ever have a property of type CGFloat*. Use CGFloat instead.

Think about what you have been doing: floatToRemember is a method parameter, which is roughly the same as a local variable. You are taking the address of that variable and store it. Then your method returns. Which means the local variable disappears. Which means its address is now utter rubbish. Actually worse than utter rubbish; it is an indeterminate value, and almost any operation using it is undefined behaviour which can crash your program immediately if you are lucky (or can crash your program when a customer uses it, if you are unlucky).

Comment: EDIT: I get what you're saying now. I took away the pointer in the header and than changed it in the two methods below. Thanks for pointing out my simple mistake :)

Comment: Could be phrased nicer, but this correct. Primitives are small enough to be accessed directly, instead of by reference, so to copy them just assign them. There are times you'll want a pointer a primitive as a method parameter, but it's a more advance use case.

Comment: The short answer is that CGFloat is an primative type - you don't need to do anything to copy it.  Just assign it.